# symfony boolean field into form

Tags: php, symfony

I have this field in entity:

```
/**
* @ORM\Column(type="boolean")
*/
protected $done = 0;
```

In database it's `tinyint(1)`. When I try to add it into a form:

```
$builder
   ->add('done', 'checkbox')
```

It throws an error:

```
Unable to transform value for property path "done": Expected a Boolean.
```

Huh? Isn't it boolean?

Comment: try with choice instead of checkbox

Comment: I don't want it to be select box, just a simple checkbox.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

0 or 1 are not booleans. They are integers. Use true/false in your domain model.

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="boolean")
 */
protected $done = false;
```

Answer (score 8):

thanks a lot for the solution but this didn't work for me. I use symfony 4. This is how I accomplished,

Entity,

```
/**
* @ORM\Column(type="boolean")
*/
protected $done = 0;

public function getDone(): ?bool
{
    return $this->done;
}

public function setDone(?bool $done): self
{
    $this->done = $done;

    return $this;
}
```

FormType,

```
->add('done', CheckboxType::class, array(
    'required' => false,
    'value' => 1,
))
```

I needed to add use CheckboxType since I call the class. 
(use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\CheckboxType;)
**If you run "php bin/console doctrine:migrations:diff" db will add tinyint(1)
field**